# Data Uri for each intent in android

Tags: android, android-intent

Android defines various of intent actions, How can I know what uri-data I can use with each intent?

Comment: some useful info at [Content Providers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Comment: maybe you don't understand my question. I want to know what Uri-data types which I can use for EACH intent.

Comment: maybe you can elaborate on your question with an example

Comment: I just want to have a full reference to all Action in android. And Each action (such as Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Intent.ACTION_EDIT,...) I want to see a full reference of all Data URI which it can receive. You can see an example at http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html, but I think it does not contain full story.

Comment: it will be difficult a full list of such events at any place. Is there a specific intent/functionality you're looking for?

Comment: I just want to see a full list of actions which were defined by Android. Is it so hard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I know what uri-data I can use with each intent?

In some cases, it may be described in the documentation of the action. In other cases, the action is generic (e.g., `ACTION_EDIT`), and so there may be any number of possible MIME types that will be supported, depending on what software is installed on the device.

> And Each action (such as Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Intent.ACTION_EDIT,...) I want to see a full reference of all Data URI which it can receive.

That is not knowable in advance. It depends on what software is installed on your device.

> I just want to see a full list of actions which were defined by Android

There is no such list.

Comment: SO, Why is there not any full-list of Data URI for each Android-Defined actions? (suppose that We don't care about user-define actions)

Comment: @Nguyen Minh Binh: Presumably because the Android engineers are busy doing other things that will do more to help improve Android. You are welcome to sift through the source code and create your own list, then contribute it back to the Android open source project, if you so choose.

Comment: Unbelievable ! Create this list may not take much time that is no one did.